# What is the best approach. Executor framework or a normal thread ? Thread has to be designed to run once every hour and do a batch operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm thinking to make a thread sleep for 1 hour after every operation. A kind of while loop running.

Comment: Go for a scheduler (timer).

Comment: Executors are usually preferable, also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094867/when-should-we-use-javas-thread-over-executor

Answer (score 1):

When you want to run a task in specific intervals, you should use the [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class to [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) a [java.util.TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) at regular intervals.

When you make the thread sleep for one hour after finishing the task, then the interval will be actually one hour plus the execution time, not exactly one hour. Even when your batch task only takes a few seconds, the time difference accumulates over time.

That means that the actual time on which your task runs will become less and less predictable over time. I don't know how important it is for your use-case that your batch process happens at predictable moments or that it is executed exactly 168 times per week, but when it matters, the solution with sleep would be quite bad.

Comment: Agree. I would be using the Timer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy approach whould be to Use [ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)