# Safe to start thread without keeping reference?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm starting my thread like so:

```
(new MyThread()).start();
```

I'm not keeping a reference to it anywhere, so I'm wondering if it's a safe approach - can't GC collect it since it's not referenced?

---

If not (I think so), then why?

Comment: GC can collect them, just make sure the code in `run` method finishes correctly. Also, use `ExecutorService` instead of using plain `Thread`s naively.

Comment: Today i had same question in my MIND!!! :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that's not what I meant, anyway, could you explain why is ExecutorService better than this? Advantages?

Comment: The *thread* (the actual thread) is [it's *own* GC root](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2423293/2864740).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Thread Garbage collected or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423284/java-thread-garbage-collected-or-not)

Comment: Read here: [When should we use Java's Thread over Executor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1094867/1065197), when you may infer from all the answer that `ExecutorService` provides a better interface to work with concurrency than using threads alone.

Comment: Thread and ExecutorService serve different purposes.  Create a Thread when you need a long running task that _waits_ for something (e.g., waits for keyboard input, waits for network connections)  Use an ExecutorService when you want to parallelize a computation that can be broken up into two or more finite tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [OpenJDK Java 7 source code of `Thread`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Thread.java?av=f), you'll notice that [`start()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.start%28%29) contains the following

```
group.add(this);
```

where `group` is the `Thread`'s `ThreadGroup` which is managed by the JVM. So there is always a reachable reference to the `Thread` while it is still running. It won't be garbage collected

---

If this alone isn't convincing, consider that starting a new thread means creating a new call stack where the root call is one of `Thread`'s methods, probably some `native` method. You can't be executing the method of an object if the object is garbage collected. As such, the `Thread` object must still be alive.

Comment: Ahh, very cool. I thought the reachability was ensured at a lower-level.

Comment: @user2864740 There's definitely more to it than this, but just this, I think, is enough to confirm that it won't be GC'ed.