# Do I need to call join() when stopping a Thread in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have these 5 simple thread that run a while loop:

```
flasherThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running.get()) {
            // do network stuff         
        }
    }
});
```

`running` is declared as `private final AtomicBoolean running;`.

I have this method:

```
public void stopFlasherThread() {
    running.set(false);
}
```

My question is by setting the flag to false that stops the thread immediately ? Or do I need to call `flasherThread.join()` to make sure that the thread has stopped ?

The main issue is that I have 4-5 of these at a time.

So I have a loop such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ThreadArrayList.get(i).stopFlasherThread();
    ThreadArrayList.get(i).join()  // should I do this ?
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: `Thread#join` just waits until the specified thread dies.  If that's what you intend to happen, then you should call it.

Comment: Exiting the run method stops the thread. Period.

Comment: You don't really need to create your own interrupt system, it [already exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Comment: @D.B and use interrupt ?

Comment: If you want to save the Thread-Management you can use a Fork-Join-Pool. To this pool you send RecursiveActions or RecursiveTasks, which are proccessed on different threads. The Actions/Tasks do not have to be recursive, but can be if you create subproblems and submit it to the pool. Here you find an long explanation: http://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join and here a fibonacci example: https://dzone.com/articles/a-look-at-forkjoinpool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation on join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html):

> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,
>
> `t.join();`
>
> causes the current thread to pause execution until `t`'s thread terminates.

So, no... or not necessarily, only if you need the result of the work of that thread to do something. The `join` will not stop / interrupt the thread, it will wait for it to finish its work. The `stopFlasherThread` will make the loop stop.

I would advise you to follow a different approach on using threads on Java using [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). For example:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<AtomicInteger> futureResult = executor.submit(new Callable<AtomicInteger>() {
    @Override
    public AtomicInteger call() {
        // Here I return a random integer, but you can do your proper calculation
        AtomicInteger atomicInteger = 
            new AtomicInteger(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + atomicInteger);
        return atomicInteger;
    }
});

// Thread returns result, but continues to execute as it is a single thread pool
try {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + futureResult.get());
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Handle exception properly
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // Handle exception properly
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Stop all threads
executor.shutdownNow();
```

There I define an inline class that extends the [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface and implement the `call` method to perform a task in another thread. This returns the result of the computation in the variable `futureResult` which is a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). Since executor is a thread pool, it continues to be available to take tasks even though our task here has already been resolved. To finish the whole thread pool loop you can do a `executor.shutdownNow()`.

Comment: For most usual cases and when you have a lot of threads it provides cleaner code and it makes your code less complex. Here is some debate  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1094867/3294286 but overall Executors are prefered. I used them in production systems to handle multiple requests to backend / external systems and works well.

Comment: is this still ok if I am running while true loops that do not return anything ? Because I read about future tasks..

Comment: If you use Future and Callable, you wouldn't really need those loops. They do asynchronous work and do not care about the result or you could add timeouts to the futures (very useful for connecting with other services / applications) or you could wait for execution to end with invokeAll. Here I found a nice tutorial you may look: https://www.callicoder.com/java-callable-and-future-tutorial/ Using this combined with ExecutorService gives you very powerful tools to make a clean backend server with heavy multithreading.

Comment: I don't really understand. Callable and Future Do care about the result, that is the whole point as they return a value... How will that help me get rid of loops ?

Comment: A future.get() will return the result when it is available. And executorService.invokeAll() will wait for the result of the future.get() of all the callables in the thread pool. If any of your callables fails on an exception. The invokeAll method is blocking if that is what you are looking.

Comment: I dont want to block anything if that makes sense, I am getting the response from the server and posting it on the UI, which is a camera preview, so I can't block that

Comment: @TrtTrt I modified my answer to show you a piece of working code with Executor, Callable and Future.